# iPad Orientations

Tags: ipad, orientation

Ok here is the structure of the app:

in delegate, i add rootViewController as subview to the window:

```
RootViewController *rootView = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

[window addSubview:rootView.view];
```

In rootViewController there is an inteface I crate programmatically (a brunch of buttons like the springboard), and is currently working only in portrait mode.

When I add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    NSLog(@"we are here");

    return YES;


}
```

nothing happens, its called just when the app runs, and not when I change orientations.

So what I miss ?
How I will make my View controller rotate based on orientation?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You should configure your **Info.plist** correctly

Check if the **UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad** (*Supported interface orientations (iPad)*) array is present, if not add this node and the orientations you want to be supported in your app.

[image]

Comment: yep, forgot to say that I have allready setup info.plist. I have 4 items in that array, one for each orientation.

Comment: Have you some other viewControllers or RootVC is the only one ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found the solution

Looks like based on the apple docs I have to add the RootViewController as retainable property and then orientations work as it should.

Thanks for the help anyway.