# Landscape to portrait orientation not working in ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have used following methods for changing the orientation but it doesn't calls. Why it's so?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            [self potraitFrame];
        }
        else
        {
            [self landScapeFrame];
        }
}
```

//Auto Rotating Methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    BOOL returnval=NO;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            [self potraitFrame];
        }
        else
        {
            [self landScapeFrame];
        }
        returnval = YES;
    }
    return returnval;
}
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            [self potraitFrame];
        }
        else
        {
            [self landScapeFrame];
        }
    }
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //    UIInterfaceOrientation crntOrntatn = self.interfaceOrientation;
    //    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(crntOrntatn) ? crntOrntatn : UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return self.interfaceOrientation;
    }
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;   
    }
}
```

Comment: supportedInterfaceOrientations is called or not?

Comment: and viewcontroller is added as subview or directly pushed or presented from other viewcontroller?

Comment: Make sure you have configured your "Info.plist" correctly. [This answer shows you how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3565846/981049).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i did it correctly.  Supported Interface Orientations (iPad)
 <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
 <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
 <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
 <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>

Comment: @cjd supportedInterfaceOreintations is not called, and viewController is pushed.

Comment: @Manimaran check this below code its working give me vote ya .... i want reputation ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
[super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
    ||  toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    Nslog(@"Landscape");
}
else
{

    Nslog(@"Potrait");

}

}

 this code it will be use full for rotation....and u can write in viewwillappear like this


  UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{


    //Do your stuff for landscap

} else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)

{


}
```

Comment: willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation not working?

Comment: ur using storyboards or xibs tell me first

Comment: i am using xibs but i am not implementing on it, i m doing all that UI in code itself.